# Find the hex code for a transparent color

Tags: color, color-reproduction

In the image below, there are four colors. Three of them are opaque, and two of those opaque ones are behind a semi-transparent color. I want to find the exact hex value and opacity of that color.

[image]

Bonus question: figure out which website this image is from.

Comment: Try (RGB) = (73, 152, 255) with 35% opacity. Numbers have base=10. No guarantee, I cannot be sure how close the shown image is to your original. Can easily cause 1 unit errors.

Comment: @user287001 Thanks! It was the same color as one of the opaque ones, but with 35% opacity exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (RGB) = (73, 152, 255) with 35% opacity. Numbers have base=10. No guarantee, I cannot be sure how close the shown image is to your original. Can easily cause 1 unit errors due roundings.

ADD: It's calculated with the well known elementary mix formula. RGB component A in top layer with opacity P and the same color component B as opaque in bottom layer give mix PA+(1-P)B. assuming everything happens in the same color space. That's a strong assumption, I guessed your image was originally sRGB and your system obeys the same mixing as Photoshop by default with no mixing gamma settings.

The elementary (some of us would say naive) mixing formula gives enough equations from where the opacity and R,G and B are solved. Actually there are 2 more equations than those 4 which is the minimum. They could be used for finding the best match. Imgur image service and web applications between us change your image and as said, the mixing process in your system was only guessed to be the same as in Photoshop by default.

Comment: Yep! The RGB is off by a bit - it's actually 76, 151, 255. But the opacity was perfect! How did you find out? Was it just trial and error, or did you use something else?